# Live update map - Timer class - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, google-maps, timer

I'm building a project with asp.net. 
Part of the the project is a view (using google maps api) that is showing the the status of the parking lots with maerkers on the map.
Im using JSON file to create the markers.

Moreover, Im using arduino with some sensors that are indicated of the parking lot status.

I want that this Json will be update (override the previous) **every 2 seconds** (so that if a car enters the parking lot and now its full - it will present on the map as full)

I have 2 functions that creates this Json's and I want to call them every 2 seconds as I said before.

I could not do it. I'll be glad to receive your help.

The name of the view page: "TotalPs".

This is the controller in which the relevant function is located:

```
    public ActionResult TotalPs()
    {

        ViewBag.Message = "TotalPs";
        return View();

    }

    public ActionResult TotalPData()
    {
        ReadArduino(); //READ THE DATA FROM THE ARDUINO
        callA(); // CREATES THE FIRST JSON
        callB(); // CREATES THE 2ND JSON


        var totalQueryParkingLot =
                from lot in db.parkingLots
                orderby lot.PricePerHour
                select lot;

        return Json(totalQueryParkingLot);
    }

    public void callA()
    {

        var totalQueryParkingLot =
                from lot in db.parkingLots
                orderby lot.PricePerHour
                select lot;

        var data2 = totalQueryParkingLot.ToList();

        var jsonString2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data2);

        if (jsonString2 != null)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Content/")))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Content/"));
            }

        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Content/TotalJsonPL.json"), jsonString2);

    }

    public void callB()
    {

        var FreeQueryParkingLot =
           from pub in db.publicParkings
           orderby pub.PricePerHourpublicParking
           select pub;

        var data8 = FreeQueryParkingLot.ToList();

        var jsonString3 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data8);

        if (jsonString3 != null)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Content/")))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Content/"));
            }

        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Content/TotalJsonPU.json"), jsonString3);

    }

        public void ReadArduino()
    {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
        port.BaudRate = 9600;
        port.PortName = "COM3";
        port.Open();

        bool status1 = true;
        bool status2 = true;
        bool status3 = true;
        char[] arr = new char[4];


       String data_arduino = port.ReadLine();


            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                char first = data_arduino[i];
                arr[i] = first;
            }


        int space = arr[0] - 48;

        var arduinoQuery1 = from b in db.parkingLots where b.parkingLotID == 22 select b;

        foreach (parkingLot parkingLot in arduinoQuery1)
        {
            parkingLot.freeSpaces = space;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

In the view I call the function TotalPData() that is calling to the other functions.

[image: View]

**Tnx!!**

Comment: You need to stop using variable names like *url5* and *data6*. It's a clear path to disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are applying a ajax call to retrieve json data. So, you can assign interval using `setInterval` to execute ajax call periodically.

```
var interval = setInterval(ajaxCall, 5000); //5000 MS == 5 seconds

function ajaxCall() {
   clearInterval(interval);
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'Controller/TotalPData',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            interval = setInterval(ajaxCall, 5000);
            // Do something
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {

        }
   });
}
```

Also, It could be better to use `SignalR` to perform this kind of requirements.

[SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started)

Comment: Ive added apic of the view. can U look it pliz?

Comment: I dont want to do : <script>setTimeout("window.location.reload();", 5000);</script> because its not looks good. I need to call the callA % callB functions that creates the JSON files, and to call the  $.getJSON function every X seconds.

Comment: "because its not looks good" what is that mean ? There are basicly two options which is using SignalR and pushing the data to client side periodically or you should create a timer in the client side and apply requests.

Comment: "because its not looks good" refers to making "refresh" the page every x seconds

Comment: It will not refresh the page. It will call "ajaxCall" method for every 5 seconds.